# Bukkit Strings Not Reading Correctly

Tags: java, arrays, string, bukkit

I am trying to create a plugin for a Mincraft Bukkit server, and I have come across some problems with reading arguments for a command that are stored in an array of Strings. Here is my code for the whole plugin. (The purpose of the plugin is to allow you to change you name to a different name in-game. I know this has been made already, but I wanted to remake it for practicing making plugins...)

Main.java

```
package me.DarkSun159;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.permissions.Permission;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

    Permission makeNicks = new Permission("makeNicks");

    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new EventListener(this), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().addPermission(makeNicks);

        this.getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        this.saveConfig();

        getLogger().info("+------------------------------------+");
        getLogger().info("|DSP's NickName Mod had been enabled.|");
        getLogger().info("+------------------------------------+");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable(){
        this.saveConfig();

        getLogger().info("+-------------------------------------+");
        getLogger().info("|DSP's NickName Mod had been disabled.|");
        getLogger().info("+-------------------------------------+");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args){

        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("nick") && sender instanceof Player){
            Player player = (Player)sender;

            if(args == null || args.length == 0 || args.length > 1){
                messagePlayer.error(player, "Usage:\n     /nick <nickname>");
                return false;
            }
            else if(args[0] == "Admin" || args[0] == "admin" || args[0] == "Administrator" || args[0] == "administrator" || args[0] == "Mod" || args[0] == "mod" || args[0] == "Moderator" || args[0] == "moderator"){
                messagePlayer.warning(player, "You cannot use " + args[0] + " as you nickname...");
                return false;
            }
            else if(args[0] == "normal"){
                this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection(player.getName()).set("", null);
                messagePlayer.success(player, "You name has been set back to " + player.getName() + "!");
                this.saveConfig();
                return true;
            }
            else{
                this.getConfig().addDefault(player.getName(), args[0]);
                messagePlayer.success(player, "You nickname has been changed to " + args[0] + "!");
                this.saveConfig();
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

EventListener.java

```
package me.DarkSun159;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;

public class EventListener implements Listener{
    Main plugin;

    public EventListener(Main plugin){
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onSpeech(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e){
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        String message;

        if(plugin.getConfig().contains(player.getName())){
            message = ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "[" + plugin.getConfig().get(player.getName()) + "] " + ChatColor.RESET + e.getMessage();

            for(Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){
                p.sendMessage(message);
            }

            e.setCancelled(true);
        }


    }

}
```

Now, most of it works without a hitch(I am still developing it, so it may not look complete), but when you load it in you server, it will allow you change you name to the names I told it to not let you(Admin, admin, Mod, mod, Administrator, administrator, Moderator, moderator, normal). I've looked at my code a thousand times, but I still don't see why it lets people change their name to the prohibited names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args[0] == "Admin" || args[0] == "admin" ...` is your problem.

Don't check `String` equality with `==`, use `String.equals()`

`args[0].equals("Admin")` will return `true` when `args[0]` is `Admin` but `args[0] == "Admin"` will not. This is because `==` checks to see if the values are the same object.

Furthermore, checking for `Admin` and then `admin` is sub optimal. A user could enter `ADMIN` for example, and get away with it. Personally, to remove case sensitivity, I would do something like the following. `args[0].toLowerCase().equals("admin")`. This means that whether the user enters `admin`, `ADMIN`, `Admin`, `aDmIn`, or any other case combo, they will be refused.

I hope this clears up your frustration.

On a rather separate note, I have Bukkit plugin dev in my past, and I found that `return false` is best for the console, and that you should always `return true` to a user, as, older versions for sure (not sure about newer versions) of CB will print the command usage as it is defined in `plugin.yml` to the user in chat. If you're doing your own error messages, turn off the CraftBukkit ones, and `return true` if the command sender is a user, and not console.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you much! I come from a c++ background, so I guess that's why I thought that would work. Thanks!

Comment: I came from a C# background to learn Java, and I found myself able to use the language, but things like this tripped me up. Reading the basic tutorials from Oracle cleared up things like this, so I'd recommend that you do the same. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html